# android webview custom headers not going out on page resource requests

Tags: android, webview, request-headers

In my android app I am connecting to a secure site where my login credentials are contained in custom headers. I am able to log in successfully because the custom headers are sent with the new page request. 
Based on my custom header information there is specific page functionality which is enabled for my device. The problem is that when I load resources from the home page after login the custom headers that I specify in the webview.LoadUrl(); are not sent. So the end result is that I can log in but do not receive the special functionality that is associated with my device.

I have tried both of these overrides. shouldOverrideUrlLoading seems to work when changing URL's but shouldInterceptRequest does not seem to get called on resource requests? If it is my implementation does not work?

```
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            request.getRequestHeaders().putAll(getExtraHeaders());
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url, getExtraHeaders());
                return false;

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this works a little better for you:

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.loadUrl(url, getExtraHeaders());
            }
        });

        // true means: yes, we are overriding the loading of this url
        return true;
    }
```

This additional code is just a suggestion/outline and should not be taken as cut/paste ready code

```
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

        String mimetype;
        String encoding;

        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.putAll(request.getRequestHeaders());
        headers.putAll(getExtraHeaders());

        URL url = request.getUrl().toString();
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        for (String key : headers.keySet()) {
            conn.setRequestProperty(k, headers.get(k));
            // TODO look for the mimetype and encoding header information and set mimetype and encoding
        }

        return new WebResourceResponse(mimetype, encoding, conn.getInputStream());
        // return null here if you decide to let the webview load the resource
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much for the reply.

Comment: Actually my implementation of shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is working fine. It is getting called on every new page request and the headers are being added. The problem occurs after the initial load when the webview starts to request the page resources. Every resource request is missing the Extra headers. 
Heres an example. If I load a header test page "http://www.procato.com/my+headers/" in my web view as soon as the page loads I see all the correct headers. 2 seconds later when the page loads the images on the right hand side the extra headers are not in the request.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a possible suggestion.  The images go through `shouldInterceptRequest()` so you can actually handle the request there yourself with a `URLConnection`.  I wrote some code to give you an idea, but I haven't tested it or anything.  Hopefully it will give you the inspiration for the last piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Thanks Kris I will finish the approach and test it tomorrow morning. Chris

Comment: Hi, Well this did work in giving me access to all the resource requests. The problem I found was that intercepting all the resource requests to manually add the custom headers greatly slowed down the page load times. I had to abandon this approach and ended up adding an encrypted identifier to the user agent. The user agent is sent with all requests including resource requests. I'm not very happy with the solution but it does work and does not slow down page loads... Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a different approach, store whatever your need in a cookie for your host using WebKit's CookieManager and use the request's cookie header instead of your custom headers